# How to open drawer programatically on press in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to open app drawer while clicking floating button, but its not opening. Kindly suggest if there is any other thing other than drawer i am looking to build filter section

here is my part of the code

```
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
      new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); // 
 drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed code here!

            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
           
          },
          label: Text(
            'Filter',
            style:
                TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt, color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
```

I am getting error

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass _scaffoldKeyparamater to your scaffold.

```
Scaffold(key: _scaffoldKey);
```

Comment: not `Drawer(key: _scaffoldKey);` but `Scaffold(key: _scaffoldKey,  ...)`

Comment: Not tested but if you say so it must be true. Thank you ^^

Comment: I checked after you said, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to set key property in scaffold.

```
Scaffold(key:_scaffoldKey)
```

Then use same method as you are using.